# Getting value of an object in collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have created drop down list for employees.

- What I want?

I want to select full Name for each one of them.

- Type of form:

I use simple_form.
I actually have:

```
= f.input :person_id, label: "Employee", collection: @employee, prompt: "Select employee"
```

Result(I know, that is reference):

[image]

Before I use collection_select, but simple_form doesn't support validation for this type of collection.
Code for collection_select. This type of drop down list displays properly full name.

```
= f.collection_select :person_id, @employee, :id, :fullName, {prompt: "Wybierz pracownika"}, {class: "form-control"}
```

Update:
fullName is a method in a person.rb model.

```
 def fullName
   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
 end
```

Object employee.

```
@employee = Person.where.not(type: "Client")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is :

```
= f.select :person_id, options_for_select(@employees.map{|e| [e.fullName, e.id]}), {:prompt=>"Wybierz pracownika", :required => true}
```

It will show full names as select options and will dispatch ids as values with form.

Comment: When I use your code there is a syntax error: unexpected '|', expecting ')'

Comment: Work properly: f.select :person_id, options_for_select(@employees.map{|e| [e.fullName, e.id]}), {:prompt=>"Wybierz pracownika", :required => true}

Comment: @LukaszKorol answer updated. If it works mark it as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You follow this code like below:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:person_id, Model.all, :person_id, :fullName,{:prompt=>"Wybierz pracownika"}, {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
```

You will replace your model_name.

Or

```
= f.input :person_id, label: "Employee", collection: @employee.fullName, prompt: "Select employee"
```

I think will help you